# Membership Level issue in NationBuilder

Tags: membership

I have a website built in NationBuilder. There I needed to make another Membership level. I have done that. But the issue is that it is not showing in "Who can view this page" dropdown in page settings. Anyone has any idea how to do that.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't control who can view this page via membership levels.

From a NationBuilder FAQ, [How do I set up a five-tier membership site](http://nationbuilder.com/redtimmy/how_do_i_set_up_a_five_tier_membership_access_site):

> In NationBuilder... being a member is a binary state: you either are
>   or you are not a member. While NationBuilder allows you to sell
>   various membership levels, the database doesn't recognize those
>   various levels as distinct and different from a permissions level.
>   That means that if you make a page viewable to "Members" it will be
>   viewable to all members, equally.
>
> There's really no good workaround for this that's based on membership
>   level of which I am aware. You can, however, use conditional liquid
>   tags to display different content on a given page to logged-in users
>   depending on what tags their NationBuilder profile has. Since each
>   membership level can be configured to automatically tag people, this
>   method could be employed to display different content to individuals
>   who have different membership levels (or none at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by editing the page template. For instance, suppose you wished to restrict a page to only users with `MEMBER_A` membership.

```
{% assign hasPagePermission = false %}

{% for membership in request.current_signup.memberships %}
  {% if membership.membership_type_name == "MEMBER_A" and (membership.status == "active" or membership.status == "grace period") %}
    {% assign hasPagePermission = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if hasPagePermission == true %}
  {{ page.basic.content }}
{% else %}
  {% include 'access_denied' %}
{% endif %}
```

I realise that your original post was six years ago, however I post this in the hope that it will be helpful to others (or indeed me when I forget how to do this and end up searching for this again!)